Handling "new" keyword when mixing C and C++
I am trying to integrate a static library compiled with C++ into a C project. This basically involves linking the static library (developed with Qt) with the object files from my C module. The target is ARM CORTEX-M7.
I'm facing a problem with the usage of the "new" keyword in my C++ module. I have defined the heap section in my linker script, but since the C++ module is not aware about this, it results in the memory being allocated at a base address of 0x0, which leads to an exception.I would like to understand how to pass the heap start address to my C++ module during compilation so that dynamic memory allocation occurs in the correct area.

You need to have a C++ main and use the C++ linker.  As the C runtime start-up does not correctly initialise C++.

Check if your use of new is suitable for an embedded system. Are there any coding rules that may forbid dynamic memory allocation?

new (if not overloaded by the library) simply calls the global ::operator new function to allocate memory. This should have a default implementation in the C++ runtime which you should link into your binary (e.g. by using g++ instead of gcc in the linker phase which will select the necessary libraries by default). The default implementation typically then calls into malloc and from there everything should work just as in C. You also need to link the C++ runtime for exception support etc.

Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?

I wouldn't use C++ or QT either. Unless your definition of an embedded system is "laptop PC".

There's no problem with C++ or Qt on an embedded Cortex A-something. Those are competitive with x86. An Cortex-M7 on the other hand is rather low-power.

C++ & QT can be used (and are used on Cortex-Mx targets without any problems if the programmer knows how to use C++ on such targets.

"integrate a static library compiled with C++ (Qt) into a C project.". This is very bad idea. Qt framework has QCoreApplication which must be instantiated in main function. Many parts of Qt are assuming that there is an instance of QCoreApplication and may crash if there is none. Since you have C project this means you do not have this instance. Now question is what kind of Qt functionalities you are using and if they are depending in QApplicaiton? Most probably you should "promote" your project from C to C++ to address this issue.

Maybe How to use C source files in a C++ project? will help. My answer there also works correctly for C++ source files in a C project. The key points are (1) write the main() function in a C++ file, and (2) link with the C++ compiler.

IMO there is not enough information in this question. Please at least provide crashed thread call stack, but IMO you should provide lots of more details to receive some solid answer. Note that Qt do not uses exceptions, so actually you must have a crash.

"since the C++ module is not aware about this" - that should not be the case, the default implementation of new will use the C library malloc() in most cases.  However it is critical to have a valid C++ runtime start-up.  In addition to the C runtime, C++ requires static constructors to be invoked, and possibly additional library initialisation.  You main() function should have C++ linkage and be linked with the C++ library - even if you are largely not using it, the `new operator at least is part of the library.


I'm facing a problem with the usage of the "new" keyword in my C++
module.

Do not use malloc style allocations in the embedded programs. I would suggest using statically allocated memory pools and object pools for that. Otherwise tiny heap will fragment in no time.
To achieve it you will have to overload the new operator.
Bear in mind that exceptions, RTTI, stl, boost and other fancy C++ libraries are not suitable for embedded targets.

I am trying to integrate a static library compiled with C++ into a C
project. This basically involves linking the static library (developed
with Qt) with the object files from my C module. The target is ARM
CORTEX-M7.

Unfortunately, it is almost impossible. A good rule of thumb is: 'You can use C code within C++, but avoid using C++ code within C.'

It is possible to write C headers for a library with C++ content, thus all content must be initialized and accessed via the C functions. This way it is possible to downgrade a C++ library to pure C. But I agree, you should avoid it unless there is a really good reason. One of those exceptions is to make a library accessible for other programming languages, which is easier via C than C++.
